# Use member variable or static variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I have one variable that is only used inside one function.  The variable should maintain its value between function invocations, so it should be static variable. There are two ways to implement it. One is to declare it as a member variable:

```
class A{
private:
   void foo();
   int i;
}
// i is initialized to 0 in constructor
void A::foo()
{
    i++;
    if (i > 5)
        i = 0;
}
```

The other is to declare a static variable inside the function:

```
void A::foo()
{
    static int i;
    i++;
    if (i > 5)
        i = 0;
}
```

I wonder which one is preferred to use. There is no racing condition involved.

Comment: The two do different things, so there is no choice to be made. It depends on how you want the code to behave. Which you should explain better.

Comment: Found a similar topic before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694665/static-variable-vs-member?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I see a misconception in the question : the first one doesn't declare the variable `static`. Only the second one does. In the first one, the variable is an *instance* variable i.e different instance of the class will have their own variables, but in the second case it is (usually called) a class variable which means it is shared by *all* instances. You must *understand* this difference first before you ask any further question.

As to which one is better, depends on how/why you want to use it which is not clear from your question. It is also not clear why you want to use a class and non-static member function at all.

Comment: I didn't down vote. But I think you are not answering the question but just stating the difference between static and instance variable. That may be the reason to down vote

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne The question isn't really answerable, because OP is asking for a choice between two different and incompatible "solutions". This answer shows that, and is therefore useful to OP.

Comment: @Thusitha Thilina Dayaratne: I think my answer attempt to clear the *misconception* in the question, as the OP seems to think non-static class member are *static* member variables. So it is appropriate for me to state the difference between them.

Comment: @Nawaz. Yep Now your answer is good. I mean before your edit :) Anyway I'm not the one who down voteed

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne: No. It was good before as well :P. Note that it still doesn't answer the question, because it is not clear what the question is in the first place, though my so-called answer attempts to remove the misconception based on which the question is formed.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a static variable inside a member function, all instances of the class share the same variable. So for example:

```
void Foo::foo()
{
    static int i = 0;
    std::cout << ++i;
}

// ...
Foo foo, foo2;
foo.foo();  // i = 1
foo2.foo(); // i = 2
```

However, a data member without the static key word is a different variable for each instance of the class. Therefore if you don't mind your instances sharing the same variable, use the second example, otherwise, use the first.

Answer (score 1):

You use a static variable when you want to access it without an instance of the class or to share it between multiple instances. And you use the member variable when you want each class instance to have its own copy of the variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an *instance* variable inside the class then you have the following effects:

- You must initialize the variable in the constructor.
- Any method in the class can access and change that variable.
- If you instantiate multiple class variables, they will all have separate copies of *i*.

If you use a *static* variable in the member function, then:

- You can initialize the variable right where it is being used.
- No other method in the class can access/change the value.
- There is a single shared value across all instantiations of the class.

These obviously are implemented differently by the compiler, but unless you can show with a profiler that this is a bottleneck in performance, you shouldn't worry about this. Instead worry about your intended behavior and which case you actually want.